# React-native Geolocation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I'm new to react. And I'm expecting to build a mobile Application from Web-App using Cordova plug-in.
So in this case I want to get the App location. I'm trying this with **react-native Geolocation**.

I followed the tutorial from facebook at [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCs-rbn9HTAhUGMo8KHWjlBp4QFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.github.io%2Freact-native%2Fdocs%2Fgeolocation.html&usg=AFQjCNFc4w3Qjlf0knrH-pwIcVcO_7tW3g). But when I tried it, It does not show me the position. Instead value of the position change from **unknown** to **{}**.

There might be few errors I'm doing here.

1. I'm using a proxy
2. Testing this in browser not in Android or any other native device.
3. Facebook Link says it is react-native but my project was created by create-react-app which I think not React-native

If any of these is not the cause for this error, Please help.

My code,

```html
import React,{Component} from 'react';
class GeoLocation extends React.Component { 
 state = { initialPosition: 'unknown',
     lastPosition: 'unknown', };

  watchID: ?number = null; 

  componentDidMount() { 
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => { 
     var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position); 
     this.setState({initialPosition}); 
    },
     (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)), {
      enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000
     } );
      
      this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        this.setState({lastPosition});
        });
       } 
   }

 componentWillUnmount() {
  navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
   } 

   render() {
      return ( 
       <div className="main">
        <h1> Initial position:  {this.state.initialPosition} </h1>
         <h1> Current position: {this.state.lastPosition} </h1> 
       </div>
      ); 
     }
}
export default GeoLocation;
```

Answer (score 1):

At [HyperTrack](http://hypertrack.com) we have built a location service and included some React libraries and sample apps for React and Cordova found on our [Github](http://github.com/hypertrack). Likely this would solve the issues you are having with grabbing location, or at least get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks! It Seems cool, But I'm doing this for semester Project. So can't afford money for such service. How ever thanks a lot. :)

Comment: By the way links in the side nav-bar seems broken in the DOCS page! I'm having some troubles reading the docs!

Comment: @HelpingHand - the service is free for tracking, and in "sandbox" / test mode you can perform unlimited actions for up to 20 users.

Also, which links?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion about links! It was something with my browser. :) And thanks for the information! I feel it is a good service to give a try.

Comment: Please let us know @HelpingHand if there's anything we can do to assist you with